Undefined Symbols in xcode 15
I am building react native app and getting this error in xcode

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
_MLKLog in MLKitCommon[x86_64]7
"OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNative", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNativeCrashes", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_FKUserDefaultsPlugin", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperClient", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitLayoutPlugin", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitNetworkPlugin", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitReactPlugin", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_GDTCORTransport", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]6
"OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]200
"OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]26
OBJC_CLASS$_MLKITx_GIPLoggingReroutingGTMLogger in MLKitCommon[x86_64]200
"OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionCookieStorage", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]26
"OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]26
"OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]18
"OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponent", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]11
"OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentContainer", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]3
"OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentType", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]3
"OBJC_CLASS$_GULUserDefaults", referenced from:
in MLKitCommon[x86_64]2
"OBJC_CLASS$_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_RCTLinkingManager", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_ReactNativeNavigation", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_SKDescriptorMapper", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_CLASS$_SKIOSNetworkAdapter", referenced from:
in AppDelegate.o
"OBJC_METACLASS$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
OBJC_METACLASS$_MLKITx_GIPLoggingReroutingGTMLogger in MLKitCommon[x86_64]200
"_kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
___69-[MLKModelDownloader beginModelDownloadWithURL:modelInfo:conditions:]_block_invoke.285 in MLKitCommon[x86_64]18
___150-[MLKITx_PHTHeterodyneSyncer batchSyncWithAccounts:syncedScopes:fetchReason:throttlingCache:heterodyneSyncInfo:accountToAuthToken:lastError:callback:]_block_invoke in MLKitCommon[x86_64]48
___91-[MLKITx_PHTInternalHeterodyneSyncer syncHoldingLockWithSyncedScopes:fetchReason:callback:]_block_invoke in MLKitCommon[x86_64]51
___63-[MLKITx_GMVCloudVisionClient initWithCloudUri:apiKey:options:]_block_invoke in MLKitVision[x86_64]7
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _GULLogBasic
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNative
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_AppCenterReactNativeCrashes
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_FKUserDefaultsPlugin
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperClient
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitLayoutPlugin
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitNetworkPlugin
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_FlipperKitReactPlugin
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GDTCORTransport
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionCookieStorage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcher
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcherService
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponent
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentContainer
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentType
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULUserDefaults
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTBundleURLProvider
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTLinkingManager
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_ReactNativeNavigation
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_SKDescriptorMapper
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_SKIOSNetworkAdapter
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: _kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This looks like Objective-C classes or symbols is not found during the linking or I am not sure... .I have tried everyy possible way , it just not going away. I am stuck one day already, really appreciate some guidance, I am using xcode 15

i am using react native 0.64
